# Laravel - Migration to PGSQL error

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo

i started a project with Laravel and PostgreSQL but i can not make the migration.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find drive (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)

[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

I checked my php.ini and i've uncomment the lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

I restarted the server and when i tried again, the console gives me the same error. I checked my .env file in laravel and it's okay (i think)

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql   
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1   
DB_PORT=5432    
DB_DATABASE=laravelPSQL  
DB_USERNAME=postgres    
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

and also i checked the database.php and it's okay.

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
    'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ]
```

The last thing i did, was make a file with the function phpinfo() to see if the files of pgsql was enabled and yes.

[image]

Honestly i don't know what is happening. I tried in Wamp64, and XAMPP...and nothing. PD. I using Windows 10

Comment: Does the error occur when you run `php artisan migrate:install`? If so, you may have the extension enabled in the web version of your config, but not the CLI. Try running `php -i | grep pgsql` from the command line and see what you get.

Comment: When i run "php artisan migrate" it gives me the error in the question. But if i tried "php artisan migrate:install" it gives me: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find drive (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not null, "migration" varchar(191) not null, "batch" integer not null))

Comment: And thanks for the command but, i have Windows.

Comment: You can use something like cmder.io which sits on top of msysgit and let's you use a more Linux style terminal on windows. That's what I use on Windows 10, although I run PHP inside a VM.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, so...i run php -i | grep pgsql in the folder of my laravel project?? or in somewhere else??  o and that command, what exaxctly does it do??

Comment: It can be run anywhere. It is essentially the output of `phpinfo()` but from the command line (meaning it uses your CLI config instead of the web config). Then it pipes the output to the grep command, which filters it down to lines that contain "pgsql".

Comment: i also facing same issue, got any solution for this?

Comment: I get the same issue. Any success resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but I solved it by editing my XAMP `php.ini` file

In `php.ini` file I un-comment this line:

```
extension=pgsql
```

and then it starts working.